# DataGrid кастомная сортировка

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, .net-4.0

Необходимо решение данного вопроса :

Есть DataGrid. В него я кладу `ObservableCollection<T>`. Конечно можно туда положить `ListCollectionView`, но это мне не поможет. Так как :

1. Я пишу на .net 4.0, в .net 4.0 нету `IsLiveFiltering` и
   `LiveShaping`.
2. Я написал свой маленький `ListCollectionView` из костылей, где у
   меня две `ObservableCollection<T>`. Одна выполняет функцию `SilentArray`
   как в `ListCollectionView` - просто контейнер, и другая выполняет
   функцию `CollectionView` которая торчит наружу в UI. Я слежу за
   изменениями в своем `"SilentArray"` и решаю по фильтру что с ним
   делать - удалить из View если он там есть, оставить или добавить
   (исходя из того - подходит под фильтр или нет).

Сейчас я столкнулся с проблемой что мне нужна "живая сортировка". Допустим у вас есть лист из 10 элементов. Числа. Отсортированы они по возрастанию. И вдруг одно число поменялось, естественно в меньшую сторону или в большую. В данный момент ничего не происходит.

Но я подумал и решил - можно взять и бинарным поиском найти местечко в коллекции под данный итем. Это быстрее чем обычная сортировка `DataGrid`. Сравните сложность быстрой сортировки и бинарного поиска.

Но проблема в том что я не могу своей `DataGrid` (exDataGrid - расширенной). Обнови свой view, он просто не реагирует. Кусок кода - к чему я пришел в своих размышлениях

```
public class ExDataGrid : DataGrid
{

    private readonly object m_sync = new object();

    public static readonly DependencyProperty PropertyTypeProperty = 
        DependencyProperty.Register("ReleavntCollectionView", typeof (RelevantCollectionView), typeof (ExDataGrid), 
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata()
            {
                DefaultValue = null,
            });

    public RelevantCollectionView ReleavntCollectionView
    {
        get { return (RelevantCollectionView) GetValue(PropertyTypeProperty); }
        set { SetValue(PropertyTypeProperty, value); }
    }

    protected override void OnSorting(DataGridSortingEventArgs _e)
    {
        _e.Handled = true;
        PrepareSort(_e.Column);
        if (ReleavntCollectionView.IsCanSort)
        {
            SetSortPropertyToColumn(_e.Column);
            ReleavntCollectionView.SortByField(_e.Column.SortMemberPath, _e.Column.SortDirection.Value);

        }
    }

    private void PrepareSort(DataGridColumn _sortColumn)
    {
        if(_sortColumn == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("_sortColumn");

        if(!CanUserSortColumns || !_sortColumn.CanUserSort)
            return;

        if(!Columns.Any())
            return;

        foreach (var column in Columns)
        {
            if(column == _sortColumn)
                continue;

            column.SortDirection = null;
        }
    }

    private void SetSortPropertyToColumn(DataGridColumn _sortColumn)
    {
        if(_sortColumn == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("_sortColumn");

        ListSortDirection sortDirection = ListSortDirection.Ascending;
        if (_sortColumn.SortDirection.HasValue && _sortColumn.SortDirection == ListSortDirection.Ascending)
        {
            _sortColumn.SortDirection = ListSortDirection.Descending;
        }
        else
        {
            _sortColumn.SortDirection = sortDirection;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел решение на собственный вопрос ! Необходимо взять `BindingExpression` и обновить таргет - наш `UI Control`, а именно `DataGrid`, но при этом нельзя забывать, о том что UpdateTarget скидывает все ваши свойства в гриде до дефолтных, те которые отвечают за группировку и сортировку, поэтому надо запоминать направление относительно колонки, как была отсортирована грида.

```
public class ExDataGrid : DataGrid
{

    private readonly object m_sync = new object();

    public static readonly DependencyProperty PropertyTypeProperty = 
        DependencyProperty.Register("ReleavntCollectionView", typeof (RelevantCollectionView), typeof (ExDataGrid), 
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata()
            {
                DefaultValue = null,
            });

    public RelevantCollectionView ReleavntCollectionView
    {
        get { return (RelevantCollectionView) GetValue(PropertyTypeProperty); }
        set { SetValue(PropertyTypeProperty, value); }
    }

    protected override void OnSorting(DataGridSortingEventArgs _e)
    {
        _e.Handled = true;
        PrepareSort(_e.Column);
        if (ReleavntCollectionView.IsCanSort)
        {
            ListSortDirection direction = ListSortDirection.Ascending;
            SetSortPropertyToColumn(_e.Column, ref direction);
            ReleavntCollectionView.SortByField(_e.Column.SortMemberPath, _e.Column.SortDirection.Value);

            var bindingExpression = this.GetBindingExpression(ExDataGrid.ItemsSourceProperty);
            if (bindingExpression != null)
                bindingExpression.UpdateTarget();

            _e.Column.SortDirection = direction;
        }
    }

    private void PrepareSort(DataGridColumn _sortColumn)
    {
        if(_sortColumn == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("_sortColumn");

        if(!CanUserSortColumns || !_sortColumn.CanUserSort)
            return;

        if(!Columns.Any())
            return;

        foreach (var column in Columns)
        {
            if(column == _sortColumn)
                continue;

            column.SortDirection = null;
        }
    }

    private void SetSortPropertyToColumn(DataGridColumn _sortColumn, ref ListSortDirection _sortDirection)
    {
        if(_sortColumn == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("_sortColumn");

        ListSortDirection sortDirection = ListSortDirection.Ascending;
        if (_sortColumn.SortDirection.HasValue && _sortColumn.SortDirection == ListSortDirection.Ascending)
        {
            _sortColumn.SortDirection = _sortDirection = ListSortDirection.Descending;
        }
        else
        {
            _sortColumn.SortDirection = _sortDirection = sortDirection;
        }
    }
}
```